# How to disallow years in d3.scaleTime() axis ticks?

Tags: d3.js

With D3 (v4, upgrading to v5 is also an option), I'm plotting a time series for a time interval. The data has unknown duration, usually a number of seconds, and we have a start datestamp and an end datestamp.

What I'm currently doing to generate an x axis is like this, where `startTime` and `endTime` are numeric timestamps, `width` and `height` are numbers and `xAxisGroupSelection` is a D3 selection:

```
const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([0, startTime - endTime)
  .range([0, width])

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(this.xScale)

xAxisGroupSelection
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(xAxis)
```

Something this does very well, is it gives sensible formats for the numbers. For example it styles seconds like `:01` and milliseconds like `.500`, and if I get a rather long interval that lasts minutes or hours, it'll handle that.

The problem is, since it reads a `0` timestamp, it adds a `1970` year label to the start of the profile. That is of course the correct year for a timestamp of `0`, but I don't want it to display *any* year for a time series of seconds. Is there any way using D3 config I can keep the default time formatting, but not add ticks for year (or month, day etc)?

```
<g class="axis-group x-axis" transform="translate(0, -12)" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="middle">
  <path class="domain" stroke="#000" d="M0.5,2V0.5H0.5V2"></path>
  <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0.5,0)">
    <line stroke="#000" y2="2"></line>
    <text fill="#000" y="5" dy="0.71em">1970</text> <!-- <=== -->
  </g>
  <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0.5,0)">
    <line stroke="#000" y2="2"></line>
    <text fill="#000" y="5" dy="0.71em">.500</text>
  </g>
  <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0.5,0)">
    <line stroke="#000" y2="2"></line>
    <text fill="#000" y="5" dy="0.71em">:01</text>
  </g>
  <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0.5,0)">
    <line stroke="#000" y2="2"></line>
    <text fill="#000" y="5" dy="0.71em">.500</text>
  </g>
```

Obviously there are many roundabout ways I could remove or modify this, from using a CSS first-child rule to hide it to manually selecting it in D3 and modifying its value, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do in 
 a clean way using the D3 scale / axis / format / time APIs.

Can I tell D3's axis tick generator to ignore units of time greater than minutes? I've been through [the docs for D3 time scales](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleTime) but could't find anything. I think it might be possible using [`Time.range()`, but the docs aren't giving me many clues on how](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#time_range).

---

**Update:** It looks like I need to create a custom function to pass to `.tickFormat()`, similar to [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/wboykinm/34627426d84f3242e0e6ecb2339e9065), but duplicating the default time formatter with a cut off point added to the conditional logic. So next question: where do I find the default D3 time format logic...

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the D3 source code, it seems the default smart time tick formatter is all inside private functions inside `d3-scale/src/time.js`. It looks to be completely take-it-or-leave-it: you can either use it exactly as is, or replace it completely by passing a custom function to `.tickFormat()`.

So you need to create a custom function, duplicating the logic you want from inside the `d3-scale/src/time.js` `calendar` export, and particularly the nested `function tickFormat(date)`.

In my case an important part of it is formatting timestamp 0 as a special case that returns 0, rather than the broadest possible description of the first millisecond of 1970. So my function is essentially:

```
xAxis.tickFormat((date) => {
  // If this describes 0 milliseconds from the Epoch, return '0'
  if (d3.timeFormat('%Q')(date) === '0') return '0'
  // Then copy and paste as many lines as needed from `d3-scale/src/time.js`
  // from the `function tickFormat` adding the definitions of the formatters
  // like `formatMillisecond` etc from the `calendar` scope
})
```

I tried to find a way to extract the default tick formatter, so that I could just do the 0 check then use the default without duplicating anything, but there wasn't any way I could find to access it.

As well as the code in the D3 source there's a demo of conditional time formats in D3 here: https://bl.ocks.org/wboykinm/34627426d84f3242e0e6ecb2339e9065

Answer (score 1):

You can use .tickFormat() on your axis with formating function like this:

```
function multiFormat(date) {
return (d3.timeSecond(date) < date ? formatMillisecond
: d3.timeMinute(date) < date ? formatSecond
: d3.timeHour(date) < date ? formatMinute
: d3.timeDay(date) < date ? formatHour
: d3.timeMonth(date) < date ? (d3.timeWeek(date) < date ? formatDay : 
formatWeek)
: d3.timeYear(date) < date ? formatMonth
: formatYear)(date);
}
```

Replace "formatSomething" with formating d3.timeFormat("x"). You can find examples here https://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/raw/ca0adb7e426c12c06a95/.

Here are default values, so u can just copy thos and change year if u want to keep default behavior:

```
%Y - for year boundaries, such as "2011".
%B - for month boundaries, such as "February".
%b %d - for week boundaries, such as "Feb 06".
%a %d - for day boundaries, such as "Mon 07".
%I %p - for hour boundaries, such as "01 AM".
%I:%M - for minute boundaries, such as "01:23".
:%S - for second boundaries, such as ":45".
.%L - milliseconds for all other times, such as ".012".
```